# Buddypress for wordpress Main Activity filtering AJAX

Tags: ajax, wordpress, filtering, buddypress

I am trying to wrap my head around how these are all connected.  I am trying to add some functionality to my main activity AJAX query if a button is clicked. I see the _inc/ajax.php to edit and have looked through it, but not sure where to edit it to include new options or new loops.

As of now it seems I can find some of the features listed but I am getting stuck on how they get connected up specifically when creating my own new custom loops to be used.  I created a update-loop.php and put this in my theme folder in a new directory called 'update' but can't seem to get it loaded up correctly.

All I want is to get the filtering option to filter new blog posts. (if possible new blog posts from a specific category, which looking through the available options and don't see it anywhere).  Note I am NOT using wordpress Mu.

Thanks for any help or guidance, I have asked on the buddypress support forums (lost cause) but I never get any feedback or any peep out of any one there.

---------EDITED:

Let me clearly ask at least one question that would be very helpful in my knowledge and future development with buddypress in working using AJAX.

How can I/If possible create my own custom loops and use them within the ajax filtering options on the main activity wall?

Please any help would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: Can you post the JavaScript that's bound to the button click?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you custom functionality is (seperate) plugin but take a look at this:
http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

I'm afraid I don't understand what you are asking or what you want to do....

Comment: Hey Janw, Thanks for participating in my thread.  Are you familiar with Buddypress at all?  It has links inside its main activity wire that filter content using AJAX my question is how do I add my own links to add my own custom loops to show specific content.

Comment: @Jared No I'm not familiar with BP at all. Have you looked at the BP [codex](http://codex.buddypress.org/home/)? GL